# When I subtract two timestamps in a dataframe ,I am getting output "0 days 00:07:30" ; How do I convert it into minutes?

Tags: python, pandas

```
diff=table['DelayInMinute']=(pd.to_datetime(table['joinTime']) - 
     pd.to_datetime(table['ScheduleDateTime']))
```

> Output: "0 days 00:00:00"

```
diff_minute=pd.Timedelta(diff).total_seconds()/60.0;
```

But getting

> ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta
>   or convertible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) if multiple values of Series:

```
diff_minute=diff.dt.total_seconds()/60.0
```

If want output scalar by first value use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first value with [`Timedelta.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/panedas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html), converting to `Timedelta` is not necessary:

```
diff_minute=diff.iat[0].total_seconds()/60.0
```

Comment: excellent  answer as always!

Comment: I guess I was not using "dt." in the above code. Anyway thanks for the quick reply superman!

Comment: @pygo - Thank you, but not always...

Comment: @jezrael,  since i started learning pandas i see your ans really the good one so i can say :-)